# react-admin filter with i18n fields

Tags: filter, internationalization, react-admin, textinput

I have followed the docs of marmelab to add i18n to my react-admin, so far so good. One of my ressources has only a field that is translated in 3 languages (en.js fr.js etc.)

```
 name: {
          en: 'name',
          fr: 'name (French)',
          cn: 'name (Chinese)',
        },
```

this is the components I have tried to add a filter to

```js
    import { Datagrid, List, TextInput, TextField } from 'react-admin';
    
    function ManufacturerList() {
      const manufacturerFilter = [
        <TextInput
          source='name.en'
          alwaysOn
          resettable
        />,
      ];
    
      return (
        <List
          sort={{ field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }}
          filters={manufacturerFilter}
        >
          <Datagrid
            rowClick='show'
            bulkActionButtons={false}
          >
            <TextField source={`name.en`} />
            <TextField source={`name.fr`} />
            <TextField source={`name.cn`} />
          </Datagrid>
        </List>
      );
    }
    
    export default ManufacturerList;
```

so I have 3 problems:

1. the filter with name.en gives me an error "something went wrong", the url return after typing "Example" in the textinput filter is

http://localhost:3001/#/manufacturers?displayedFilters=%7B%7D&filter=%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22en%22%3A%22example%22%7D%7D&order=ASC&page=1&perPage=10&sort=name

2. once i figure how to use the name.en, can i replace .en by .${locale} that would match the language chose by the user?
3. my search filter before i18n where source='name.like' to have partial match, is it possible to combine this with the i18n ?

and here is the query that is shown in react query devtool

> ["manufacturers","getList",**{"filter":{"name":{"en":"example"}}**,"pagination":{"page":1,"perPage":10},"sort":{"field":"name","order":"ASC"}}]

--> if i edit the url and i get to this query below, then the filtering works

> ["manufacturers","getList",**{"filter":{"name.en":"example"}**,"pagination":{"page":1,"perPage":10},"sort":{"field":"name","order":"ASC"}}]

Comment: Passing manually the source='name.en' should do the trick. When you say it doesn't get you the proper query string, can you be more specific?

Comment: I edit my question following your comment, so far source='name.en' doesnt seem to work unless i missed something

Answer (score 0):

React-admin sees compound names as paths, so it's normal that a filter on `names.en` translates to the following `filter` value in `dataProvider.getList()`: `{"name":{"en":"example"}}`.

If that's not what your API expects, then you must do the translation in your dataProvider, by flattening the `filter` value, e.g. using the `flat` npm module.

Something like:

```
const dataProvider = {
   ...baseDataProvider,
   getList: async (resource, params) => {
      let newParams = params;
      if (resource === "manufacturers") {
         newParams.filter = flat(params.filter);
      }
      return baseDataProvider.getList(resource, newParams);
   },
};
```

Comment: ok thanks for the information, I am using the the lb4 provider and I'm not at the level yet to modify the dataProvider yet...